# Python Ignoring other if statements

Tags: python

I'm very new to python, but this is such a simple problem (and I know it should work) that it's kind of frustrating.

I have this code which should insert data to mysql db when the item is not empty. But for some reason python evaluates a particular if statement only when the if statements above it also evaluate to true.

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO `diseases`(`medical_term`, `local_term`, `date_added`, `from_getbetter`) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)""", (item['title'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['desc'][0].encode('utf-8'), now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 0))            
    disease_id = self.cursor.lastrowid
    if item['head']:
        self.cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO `disease_locations`(`disease_id`, `location`) VALUES (%s,%s)""", (disease_id, item['head'][0].encode('utf-8')))
    if item['neck']:
        self.cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO `disease_locations`(`disease_id`, `location`) VALUES (%s,%s)""", (disease_id, item['neck'][0].encode('utf-8')))
    if item['nose']:
        self.cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO `disease_locations`(`disease_id`, `location`) VALUES (%s,%s)""", (disease_id, item['nose'][0].encode('utf-8')))
    if item['mouth']:
        self.cursor.execute(""" INSERT INTO `disease_locations`(`disease_id`, `location`) VALUES (%s,%s)""", (disease_id, item['mouth'][0].encode('utf-8')))
```

For example, item['nose'] would only insert if items head and neck are not null.
[Database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT0nj.png)

Please help :(

Comment: Your check should be `if item['head'][0]:` and so on.

Comment: Instead of repeating the same code with just the key replaced, you could write that as `for location in ['head', 'neck', ...]: if location in item: ...`

Comment: @Schwern Thank you very much! Your suggestion works :) It's so much better than what I was doing

Answer (score -1):

hi I assume item is a dict, then your script will raise error if item hasn't such a key 'head'. All of your if statement should be write as following:

```
if 'head' in item:
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem stated in the question.